# Event prevent default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function below

```
function someName(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#someCont').dialog({
     width:200,
     height:auto,
     modal:true
   })
}
```

And I am using it like

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="someName()">Link Name </a>
```

but in browser it throws an error "e is not defined".
Can anybody suggest where I am doing wrong? the anchor tag could be more than 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bind a click function via jquery rather than putting it inline

```
(function($){
    $(function() {
        function someName(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        $('a').click(function(e) {
            someName(e);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

or add the parameter in the function:

```
onClick="someName(e)"
```

Comment: Please take out everything after "or add..." Inline event handlers are a horrible idea, and there's no guarantee that's going to work cross-browser.

Comment: thanks Alex.. it's working now..
#Anthony this code is from old framework, i don't have permission to change the same. however i will keep in mind for futhre thing.

Comment: you could also try to write onClick="someName(); return false;" when you dont need the event at all (which is the case when you only want to call preventDefault())

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass event object

```
<a href="#" onclick="someName(event)">Link Name </a>
```

Alternative approach could be if you do not use inline event and assign some id or class to anchor and use that to bind event.

*HTML*

```
<a href="#" id="a1">Link Name </a>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('#a1').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   $('#someCont').dialog({
     width:200,
     height:auto,
     modal:true
   })
});
```

Comment: youre missing the # in your a1 selector

Comment: Your parameter for the jQuery callback function is called `event` yet you're trying to call `e.preventDefault()` - should be `event.preventDefault()` (or call the parameter `e`).

Answer (score 0):

In `function someName(e)`, e is an event object. So whenever you are calling this function, you should pass window event object an argument like given below:

```
<a href="#" onclick="someName(event)">Link Name </a> // Here I have passed this object
```

Otherwise, you'll get the same error `'e not defined'`

Comment: Except `this` is that anchor element, not the event, so that's not going to work.

Comment: Add event.preventdefault() to avoid the default functionality of anchor link and trigger your own code for that.

Comment: Where does `event` magically come from in that function? Passing `this` as the argument for `e` and then trying to call `e.preventDefault()` isn't going to work, because `this` isn't an event that has a `preventDefault` function.